# PHP registration form not adding users to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, xampp, registration

My register.php file is working but when submit button is clicked. This is error message I get

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hamza\register.php on line 18
```

You have been registered! Return to login page

However it does not add any users to the database though, what am I doing wrong? I believe something along `INSERT INTO users VALUES` is incorrect. I searched around and spent 2 hours solving it but can't figure out what's wrong. Any help would be useful, thanks.

register.php file

```
 <?php
echo "<h1>Register</h1>";

$submit = @$_POST['submit'];

//form data
$fullname = strip_tags(@$_POST['fullname']);
$username = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword = strip_tags(@$_POST['repeatpassword']);
$date = date ("y-m-d");


if ($submit)
{

//check for existance
if ($fullname&&username&&$password&&$repeatpassword)
{

    if ($password==$repeatpassword)

    {

    //check char length of username and fullname
    if (strlen($username)>25||strlen($fullname)>25)
    {
    echo "Length of username or fullname is too long";
    }
    else
    {
        //check password length
        if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
    {
    echo "Password must be between 6 and 25 characters";
    }
    else
    {
    //register the user!

    // encrypt password
    $password = md5($password);
    $repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword);

    //open database
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("phplogin"); //select database

    $queryreg = mysql_query("


INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','".$fullname."','".$username."','".$password."','".$date."')
    ");

    die ("You have been registered! <a href='index.php'>Return to login page</a>");

    }

}


    }
    else
        echo "Your passwords do not match!";
}
else
    echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields!";

}

?>

<html>
<p>
<form action='register.php' method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Your full name:
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type='text' name='fullname' value='<?php echo $fullname; ?>'
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Choose a username:
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type='text' name='username' value='<?php echo $username; ?>'
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Choose a password:
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type='password' name='password'>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Repeat your password:
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type='password' name='repeatpassword'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>

</form>

</html>
```

Comment: As a side note, this is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - if this is for real-life use, you should look at using mysqli or at the very least using something like `addslashes()` to sanitize the input (`strip_tags` will not help you here).

Comment: It's just a sample for college assignment

Answer (score 1):

Check your 18th line:

`if ($fullname&&username&&$password&&$repeatpassword)`

You forgot to put `$` sign for **username**.

Comment: He might even have noticed this if he didn't crameverythingtogetherlikethat.

Comment: Even a text editor with decent code-coloring should show up mistakes like this (saving you hours in the long-run)

Comment: @Barmar I still get an error Notice: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hamza\register.php on line 18

Comment: @h4mza Have you changed the line to: `if ($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$repeatpassword)`? While stylistically not great, that should definitely fix this error. Also consider using [Notepad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org) or similar for code coloring.

Comment: @John Yes that's exactly what I've done. I am using Notepad++

Comment: Then not sure what to say... a quick sanity check: are you definitely viewing the same file you're editing? Add `die('test');` as the first line of the file and ensure the resulting output is `test`.

Comment: @John, turned out I saved the file in wrong directory. It's working now, error code does not show up anywhere but still not able to add users to database.

Comment: Probably a MySQL error. Do `echo mysql_error();` after running your query and you'll see what the error is.

Comment: @John Seems to be working, was able to register but incorrect password as database shows password stored as md5 sum

Comment: The number of values you're providing for the `INSERT` probably doesn't match the number of columns in the table. Either specify your columns for the `INSERT` or make sure you provide a value for **every** column of the table in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @John, all sorted now. I had to delete 3 lines starting from //encrypt password. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @h4mza Not sure why that would resolve this, and this means you're now storing passwords in plaintext, which is a big no-no. Anyway, happy this is working for you. Beware of coding style and security, if these will factor into your grade :)

Comment: @John, Yeah I know but this is just a sample as part of my college assignment. All I need is a website with registration form and be able to log in and log out. Well that's done now so I'm sorted :) Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Oh, just noticed your updated comment above. You mean you're getting "incorrect password" when trying to login? Simply `md5` the provided login password before comparing with the one in the database :)